# Select value from array using index in Python in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI tkinter based.
I recieve a string selected by user in **self.options.get()** from a list named *self.datalist1* which is taken from plc db

```
self.datalist1 = [plc_comm().data(100, 1634, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 1656, 4),plc_comm().data(100, 1702, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 1724, 4),plc_comm().data(100, 1770, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 1792, 4),
                    plc_comm().data(100, 1838, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 1860, 4),plc_comm().data(100, 1906, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 1928, 4),plc_comm().data(100, 1974, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 1996, 4),
                    plc_comm().data(100, 2042, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 2064, 4),plc_comm().data(100, 2110, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 2132, 4),plc_comm().data(100, 2178, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 2200, 4),
                    plc_comm().data(100, 2246, 3),plc_comm().data(100, 2268, 4)]
```

I want to get value of string just next to the user selected string.
For that I have a different function,

```
def select_V(self):
        a = self.options.get()
        serial_index = self.datalist1.index(a)
        x = serial_index + 1
        self.VC_selected = self.datalist1[x]
        
        return self.VC_selected
```

Expected output : String stored in the list next to selected **self.options.get()**

Eg. If user selects data in plc.comm().data(100,1634,3),

I should save data of plc.comm().data(100,1656,4) in self.selected

I'm getting error: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it is now, your code is not reproducible.

Comment: I have edited it, kindly revisit

Comment: Do you think now I can reproduce the error you get?

Comment: You want me to give you values of the datalist1? and the user value?

Comment: Yes. You don't need to give me private information, but you need to generate an example we can work with. `'NoneType' object is not iterable` means that the data is different from what you expect. At least print out the data that rises the exception. Else there is no way for us to tell what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I did not define the variable in the min function earlier i.e I used 'a' as variable instead of 'self.a', which use to give me the output as None

```
def select_V(self):
        self.value = self.options.get()
        x = self.datalist1.index(self.value)
        self.selected = self.datalist1[x+1]

        return self.selected
```

Thank you for all the support and sorry for not sharing all the information